# Load third party keyboard as becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have created a third party keyboard for a language which is not there in the default keyboard list. To use it in my app I have to go to Settings and add it manually. After that only I can use it in the app. Is there any way to add it in the code and load the keyboard in the app as `[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder]`?

Comment: what do you mean by you have created keyboard ? means are you creating keyboard by taking buttons in uiview ?

Comment: The two answers in [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656725/xcode-creating-a-custom-keyboard-just-for-my-own-app) may help you.

Comment: just need to set inputView of TextField and its done

Comment: @Lion - yes, i created it using this 
https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

Comment: then assign that view(which have keyboard keys) to your textfiels's input view! taht's it!

Comment: hi, this worked for me. thanks
And can I change the keyboard language to a language defined in the default keyboard list? Ex: Italian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your third party keyboard is a subclass of UIView then you can use textfild's "inputView" property to assign that keyboard view.

```
yourTextField.inputView = thirdPartyKeyboard
```

After this

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

will present third party keyboard instead of default keyboard.